# Naming in Rails and STI: When I have Reports (abstract) and ReportTemplates, what should "real" reports be called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, abstract, sti, terminology

I have a system where admins can create report templates, and users can create "real" reports based upon them.

As of Rails' single table inheritance mechanism, the "abstract" base model is `Report < ActiveRecord::Base`, and the template model is called `ReportTemplate > Report`. Now I need a name for the concrete instances of reports, something like `ConcreteReport > Report`, but I don't like "ConcreteReport".

Is there a better wording for this? I thought about names like `ReportItem`, `ReportInstance`..., and I like them better because they start with `Report` in the word (and not end with it, like `ConcreteReport` does), which is nicer because they are grouped together in the file browser. But they still feel crappy to me.

I also thought about an `AbstractReport` base class and then simply using `Report` for the "concrete" reports, but then I have to tweak with Rails' defaults (table name to use, etc.), which I'd rather avoid.

So any suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: Looks like you should use namespace. One Report namespace and you'll be good to go with Report::Item, etc.

Answer (score -1):

My first reaction is downrating this question cause it seems to miss the whole point of this tool in which people ask questions about issues that, most commonly, are repeating among users.

A lack of a good naming it is indeed a common problem among developers from time to time... But in this case this is SO specific to your case that I don't see how it would help anyone in the future.